# How to rename output property (defined by "as: aliasName" in the association) obtained from eager loading?

Tags: sequelize.js

I'd like to rename the property received from eager loading. Sequelize sets the name to the alias used in the association definition. For one direction of querying the name is correct, but for the other one it is not. E.g.:

Person.hasMany(Task, { as: 'owner', foreignKey: 'ownerID', constraints: true, onDelete: 'CASCADE' });

Querying:
Task.findAll({ include: Person }) 
will result in array of Task objects which have property 'owner' of type Person. And this is fine.

But querying:
Person.findAll({ include: Task}) will result in an array of Person objects containing an array of Task objects in a property named, well 'owner', while logically it is 'ownedTasks' or something.

I am able to rename the resulting property if no alias is used on the association (then it's possible to use 'as' in the 'inlude' section of config object), but alias is required if there are multiple associations between the same tables, so it is not a valid solution for me.

I also tried using "attributes: ['owner', 'ownedTasks']", but then I get an error "Unknown column 'people.owner' in 'field list'".

Is there any way to rename the property in configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rename the included model by changing the `as` name of the association.  You can also repeat an association with multiple aliases, e.g.

```
Person.hasMany(Task, { as: 'owner', ... 
...
Person.hasMany(Task, { as: 'ownedTasks', ...
```

Either alias can be used in a query.   Be cautious when you sync() either Person or Task... there could be unforeseen problems!

Answer (score 0):

Should work if you get the brackets right (around each column, containing old name and new name):

```
 Person.findAll({
   include: [
      { model: Task, attributes: [['old_name', 'new_name']]}, 
   ]
   });
```

Comment: I have:
Person.findAll({
   attributes: [['old_name', 'new_name']],
   include: [
      { model: Task, }, 
   ]
   });
The attributes in the include array refer to the names of columns extracted from task table -> building the Task object in the ‘owner’ array. I want to change the name of the whole array, not of properties of objects in the array.

Comment: My bad - I misread your question.   Possibly dumb question: why not just change the alias of the association to "ownedTasks"?

Comment: FWIW, you can repeat an association with multiple aliases, e.g. `Person.hasMany(Task, { as: 'owner', ...` followed by `Person.hasMany(Task, { as: 'ownedTasks', ...` and use either one in a query.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That actually seems to work! :D It didn't create additional FKs. Are you sure that repeating the association won't have some hidden side effects? My limited experience with Sequelize suggests that every action can have ripple effects elsewhere. PS. If you want me to upvote your answer for reputation please place it in a separate answer. I can't upvote comments yet. PS2. Simple renaming the association is not a solution, as the other query direction (owner) will be called incorrectly then.

Comment: You raise a good point.  I generally maintain schemas myself and don't use `sync()` which could have some undesired side effects.  From simple testing it SEEMS ok but I couldn't guarantee it.  Probably safer to rename the result set property in js....  Probably not worth an up vote!

Comment: I think it is worth an upvote though. If you don't set this as answer I'll create an answer with your solution. I'm going to try it out, my app is in early stage, if this doesn't work it will surface and I'll update the answer. I searched a little, but haven't found anything neither against of for using multiple aliases for the same relation.